# Как раскрыть кавычки у + и - в Python?

Tags: python-3.9

Есть функция, которая среди аргументов получает арифметическое действие. Оно естественно заключено в кавычки.
Расчёт для return происходит примерно так:

```
func_arg_1 = '10'
func_arg_2 = '5'
func_arg_3 = '+'
result = int(func_arg_1) +  func_arg_2 + int(func_arg_2)
```

Пробовал через eval но аргумент всё же раскрывает как строку

```
result = eval(int(func_arg_1) +  func_arg_2 + int(func_arg_2))
```

Возможно есть какое либо очевидное решение, но пока о нём не знаю (кодингом не так долго занимаюсь)

Пример взятый из моего кода:

```
def(self, status)
    self.cur.execute("SELECT reputation FROM profiles WHERE vkid = %s", [self.replay_id])
    rep = eval(str(self.cur.fetchall()[0][0])) + str(status) + str(self._karma(self.user_id))
```

p.s. функция self._karma возвращает int, но как видно из примера преобразуется в str

TraceBack следующий:

```
line 185, in restatus
    rep = eval(str(self.cur.fetchall()[
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Похоже, у вас фундаментальное непонимание базовых принципов программирования. Не существует никаких «кавычек», это всего лишь элемент синтаксиса языка. Существуют только типы данных — числа и строки — и их значения. Чтобы сложить два объекта, соответствующая операция сложения должна быть определена для складываемых типов. Можно сложить число с числом, можно сложить строку со строкой, но число со строкой сложить нельзя — такая операция в питоне не определена.

Comment: Функция eval принимает строку, содержимое которой будет интерпретировано как питоновый код. Значит вы должны подготовить именно строку, например вот так: `eval(func_arg_1 + func_arg_3 + func_arg_2)`

Comment: Прикинь, если я сложу "2"+"2" и 2+2, будут совершенно разные результаты и я об этом в курсе как и все остальные. Но к проблеме это никак не относится!

Comment: Так в чём у вас проблема-то? Если вы хотите сконструировать и выполнить код на лету — во втором комментарии я показал рабочий вариант

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' вот что я получаю по трейсбэку

Comment: Мой вариант кода не может выдать такую ошибку. Если он её реально выдаёт, то это может означать только то, что вы нас обманываете и какая-то из ваших переменных func_arg_1/2/3 на самом деле не является строкой.

Comment: странно, но я специально присвоил двум элементам str, для уверенности. Эти два элемента получаются из базы данных: eval(str(self.cur.fetchall()[0][0]) + status + str(1))). Но я всё равно получаю ошибку о том что инт пытается сложится с str.
 status = '10' (Например)

Comment: Значит составьте [mcve] с использованием этой самой базы

Comment: Ну так это и есть минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Одно число идёт от cur.fetchall()[0][0], другое число тоже идёт от cur.fetchall()[0][0]. Впринципе они всегда импортируются как str, но тут ещё усиленно применил str.

Comment: Не, он не воспроизводимый, так как мы достоверно не знаем, что на самом деле находится в fetchall()[0][0], а верить на слово тут не любят. Тем более по вашим словам получается, что проблемы быть не должно, а раз она есть, значит всё-таки нужен воспроизводимый пример

Comment: А ещё в процессе составления воспроизводимого примера может оказаться, что проблема не воспроизводится — и выяснится, что проблема в чём-то совершенно другом, например вы могли банально забыть перезапустить программу после изменения кода

Comment: Включил в тему отрывок из реального кода

Comment: А, так у вас же скобочки неправильно стоят. В eval нужно завернуть всё выражение целиком, а у вас там только fetchall. Обычная опечатка

Comment: И правда. Сейчас поставил скобки и всё выполнилось без ошибок. Вот что значит перегруженность... Благодарю!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в примере с `eval` убрать `int` и не путаться с именами аргументов, то все заработает.